# Is it faster to sum the rows or columns of a matrix with CUDA?

Tags: performance, matrix, cuda, sum, gpgpu

I want to compute a row-sum of an `m x n` matrix `A`, **or equivalently** the column-sum of its transpose `A'` (I have both in memory so `A'` costs me nothing extra in computation). I plan to launch `m` threads each of which can either loop over the `n` columns of `A`, or `n` rows of `A'`. Which approach will be faster if we assume the matrices are stored in **column-major format** (i.e. like with CUBLAS)?

**My thinking so far (on coalesced memory access):**

If I row-sum, then *threads in the same block* will read from adjacent memory locations *at each iteration*. Yet equally, if I column-sum instead, then *each thread* will iterate over a contiguous block of memory. So if I have threads `1`, `2` and `3` of the same block, their memory access will look like so (assuming **column-major storage**):

```
1 2 3 ... 1 2 3 ... 1 2 3 ... for row-sums
1 1 1 ... 2 2 2 ... 3 3 3 ... for column-sums
```

- But this doesn't tell me which will be faster.
- It also doesn't take into account the behavior at block-level (i.e. if the first block launched sums over rows `1-32`, will the 2nd block launched be guaranteed to sum over rows `33-64`?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"threads in the same block will read from adjacent memory locations at each iteration"

Is faster.  That is pretty much the definition of coalesced access.

Answer (score -1):

For a single thread:

```
for (i = 0 to size)
   for (j = 0 to size)
      array[i][j]
```

Will be faster than

```
for (i = 0 to size)
   for (j = 0 to size)
      array[j][i]
```

Becuase in memory each row is laid out in memory contiguously.

But for multible threads it is not as clear cut. If you spawn M threads on a M core CPU then who knows what will happen. Your L1 cache will be core specific but your L3 shared chache will probably not be very helpful assuming your overall matrix is larger than the size of the cache. I think it's fiar to say that there are too many possibilites to make a definative answer. A few thoughts:

- [Premature optimization is the root of all evil -- DonaldKnuth](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization)
- Spawning more threads than the number of cores on your machine probably will hurt more than it helps
- If you instead swpan the same number of threads as your CPU has cores start them at equaldistances apart in your matrix.

Comment: Thanks but I'm computing on a GPU, and my matrix is stored such that each *column* in laid out contiguously in memory.

Comment: The question is not posed in a general way about an M core CPU.  In the case of a CUDA GPU, with multiple threads active, the best usage of memory bandwidth occurs with coalesced access. Best overall throughput for a bandwidth-limited code will occur with best usage of memory bandwidth.  A summation of multiple elements will be a bandwidth-limited code.  So I think a definitive answer is possible.  Some of your other comments are not applicable or wrong when applied to a CUDA GPU, such as "Spawning more threads than the number of cores..."  This is usually what you want to do with a CUDA GPU.

Comment: I take it you didn't notice this is a CUDA GPU programming problem?